# Firebase dynamic links REST API returns 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create a dynamic link for my mobile app in  `node` using the `REST API` provided by firebase for dynamic links.

I have followed these [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)

I'm using `axios` to send my post request
This is my code:

```js
...
const link = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=myApikey',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            domainUriPrefix: 'https://threadsapp.page.link',
            link: `https://threads-1511.web.app/threads/${tweet.id_str}`,
            iosInfo: {
              iosBundleId: 'com.bundleId',
              iosAppStoreId: '1512677811',
              iosIpadBundleId: 'com.bundleId',
            },
            androidInfo: {
              androidPackageName: 'com.bundleId',
            },
            socialMetaTagInfo: {
              socialTitle: `A thread by ${tweet.user.name}`,
              socialDescription: `${tweet.full_text}`,
              socialImageLink: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/threads-1511.appspot.com/o/playstore.png?alt=media&token=896f4fe6-2882-442e-b15c-3767d61b8a70',
            },
            suffix: {
              option: 'SHORT',
            },
        }
      });
...
```

This is the `response`:

```
response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      vary: 'X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Wed, 03 Jun 2020 10:16:24 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      'x-xss-protection': '0',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'alt-svc': 'h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
      'accept-ranges': 'none',
      connection: 'close',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
    },
```

All my links use the `https://` or `http://` schemes as mentioned in the docs:

> At minimum, the deep-link value provided must begin with http:// or https:// schemes. It must also match any URL patterns whitelist entered in the console. Else, the creation API will fail with HTTP error code 400.

Even then I am getting this error, help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

seems like you missed the `"dynamicLinkInfo": {` part, it should look a bit like this in data

```
const link = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=myApikey',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    data: {
        dynamicLinkInfo: {
            domainUriPrefix: 'https://threadsapp.page.link',
            link: `https://threads-1511.web.app/threads/${tweet.id_str}`,
            iosInfo: {
              iosBundleId: 'com.bundleId',
              iosAppStoreId: '1512677811',
              iosIpadBundleId: 'com.bundleId',
            },
            androidInfo: {
              androidPackageName: 'com.bundleId',
            },
            socialMetaTagInfo: {
              socialTitle: `A thread by ${tweet.user.name}`,
              socialDescription: `${tweet.full_text}`,
              socialImageLink: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/threads-1511.appspot.com/o/playstore.png?alt=media&token=896f4fe6-2882-442e-b15c-3767d61b8a70',
            }
        },
        suffix: {
          option: 'SHORT',
        },
    }
  });
```